# firebase init function results in an error at collecting pip stage

Tags: firebase

I am running into a problem while running firebase init that I can't resolve.

Everything goes well until the part where it asks if I want to install dependencies. I select yes, then it gets stuck with this error message.[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxtIJ.png)

I've upgraded to pip 23.1.2 already.

What might be happening here?

Thank you

upgrade pip
reinstall pip

expecting it to not show error anymore, since pip is already latest version.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. Lastly, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). In a nutshell, include the error as TEXT in the question.

Comment: I get the same problem. I made sure I have only one python installed in my machine.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, install the dependencies in the `requirements.txt` manually:

```
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And then say `N` to installing dependencies.